# How to change the existing className into other classname?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="signin_button" tabindex="4" data-disable-with="Signing in...">
```

if this classname have a value of `btn btn-primary pull-right`, How I can change it? and make it `btn btn-primary pull-left` in javascript

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) - use toggle

Comment: Also answered in: [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)